# Testing database connection Using Javascript in outbound database connector in Mirth

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, mirth

I have database handle in channelMap (for 1 connection for all messages) and I reuse the connection for all messages. Now, before performing inserts (to a MySQL database), I want to test if the connection still exists. How do I perform this test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A crude way is to grab the connection and run a simple query (a simple SELECT or SHOW query would do) and catch the exception.

I *think* this is all based on JTDS, so you should be able to use Connection.closed which will return true if the connection is closed and false if it is open.

Comment: How about a sample script?

Comment: @GaryKindel - A sample script on a 5 year old answer will be tough! MirthConnect has been through several major release since this was posted. I believe it has some built-in connection management now. The latest version, release notes, and user guides for the FOSS version are available at https://www.mirth.com/Downloads